# Problems With 64bit Posix Write In Mac OS X? (2gb+ Dataset in HDF5)

Tags: macos, file-io, posix, large-files, hdf5

I'm having some issues with HDF5 on Mac os x (10.7). After some testing, I've confirmed that POSIX write seems to have issues with buffer sizes  exceeding 2gb. I've written a test program to demonstrate the issue:

```
#define _FILE_OFFSET_BITS 64

#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>


void writePosix(const int64_t arraySize, const char* name) {
    int fd = open(name, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT);

    if (fd != -1) {

        double *array = new double [arraySize];

        double start = 0.0;
        for (int64_t i=0;i<arraySize;++i) {
            array[i] = start;
            start += 0.001;
        }


        ssize_t result = write(fd, array, (int64_t)(sizeof(double))*arraySize);

        printf("results for array size %lld = %ld\n", arraySize, result);

        close(fd);
    } else {
        printf("file error");
    }
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    writePosix(268435455, "/Users/tpav/testfolder/lessthan2gb");
    writePosix(268435456, "/Users/tpav/testfolder/equal2gb");
}
```

Output:

```
results for array size 268435455 = 2147483640
results for array size 268435456 = -1
```

As you can see, I've even tried defining the file offsets. Is there anything I can do about this or should I start looking for a workaround in the way I write 2gb+ chunks?

Comment: What filesystem are you using?  Also print the value of `errno` when it fails; that will give you a clue to the cause.

Comment: I'm using hfs+ and the errorno is 22 (Invalid argument). This is also the same lowest level error hdf5 gives me as well.

Comment: What architecture are you using (x86 or x64)?

Comment: x64. I can fwrite just fine (though fwrite was broken up until a few months ago).

Comment: Not sure what's going on, however `write()` accepts a `size_t` length argument, not `int64_t`, so see what happens when you cast to that.

Answer (score 1):

In the HDF5 virtual file drivers, we break I/O operations that are too large for the call into multiple smaller I/O calls.  The Mac implementation of POSIX I/O takes a size_t argument so our code assumed that the max I/O size would be the max value that can fit in a variable of type ssize_t (the return type of read/write).  Sadly, this is not the case.

Note that this only applies to single I/O operations.  You can create files that go above the 2GB/4GB barrier, you just can't write >2GB in a single call.

This should be fixed in HDF5 1.8.10 patch 1, due out in late January 2013.

Comment: Could this be also the reason why I cannot read HDF5 files larger than 2 GB on my Mac that were created on a linux system?

Comment: It depends on how the data inside are organized.  If there is a single, unchunked dataset of >2GB, then yes.

Comment: The origin of the file shouldn't matter, btw.  If you are still having problems, contact the THG help desk at help@hdfgroup.org and we'll file a bug report.